# Capturing insert, update and delete events for Oracle DB in Azure

Tags: oracle, azure, azureservicebus, azure-eventgrid

We have an oracle database installed in a Azure Virtual Machine sitting in its own private VNET. We would like to capture the insert, update, delete events happening on the Oracle DB records and feed these events to some kind of queue (Service Bus Queue, Event Grid, Event Hub etc.) which can then be processed by the Azure Function or Azure Logic App.

What will be the best way to capture these events in Azure?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about the details of Azure, but I would start in the Oracle Database itself by either using the build-in [auditing](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/dbseg/introduction-to-auditing.html#GUID-16E8E421-CFCE-4584-B09B-88F01D51B152) features or custom [triggers](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/CREATE-TRIGGER.html#GUID-EE0DF3AA-7ADC-4171-B8E8-138BE9224E3B) if you need more control over what must be audited.
If you use the build-in auditing, you will then just select from the auditing views and when using a trigger you will log all the needed auditing information in the trigger and then select from the custom audit tables.

Example for auditing:

```
create audit policy my_audit_policy actions all on hr.regions; 
audit policy my_audit_policy;
```

Example for trigger:

```
create trigger aud_regions_trigger
after insert or delete or update
on hr.regions
for each row
begin
   -- log data in tables
end;
/
```